# Accessing Network through/with Active Directory (network authentication, printers, etc)

Tags: networking, windows, printing, samba, active-directory

In my High school the network (local network with printers and file server + internet access) is using Active Directory for authentication. If I want to print/access the file servers with Ubuntu I need to authenticate against the AD. Guess I'll use Samba but how exactly do you do that? Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a good article on setting up an ubuntu client to print to a networked windows printer at http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-printing.html

The article is a few years old (2009) but the procedure should be mostly the same with maybe a few minor differences.

Answer (score 1):

Try Likewise Open / Likewise open GUI to join AD. 
There is a small easy to understand guide [here](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/336477-how-to-join-a-ubuntu-machine-to-a-windows-domain).

You need to install `likewise-open`, `likewise-open-gui` and `winbind`. Then you can use GUI to setup the AD authentication. Do everything via Ubuntu software center to install dependencies along with these software.